# creating a db schema to store purchase price

Tags: mysql, sql, schema

I have a website i'm working where i need to track the price someone paid at checkout.

the product pricing can be adjusted at any time that i don't have control over.

originally i had it setup so that i never deleted prices and just calculated the price dynamically using disabled prices, but i changed that for a number of reasons. (mostly because of the overhead, but also because i added a new feature that meant that way of calculating prices was not ideal)

the main goal is for the website to be able to charge a commision on sales, so right now i have a set of invoice tables that deal with keeping track of this data, but i realized it's a bit messy the way it's set up.

i'm thinking i should move the data so that it's in a situation like this...

it's currently like this
[products] - [order_products] - [orders]

and i'd change it to add another table joined on [order_products] - [order_product_prices]

i'd just set it up so the order_products also references the price used, but the websites can sell tickets to events that span multiple days, and each of those days are ticketed individually, so while the product is [event_one] it's priced like [event_one_day1], [event_one_day2], [event_one_day3] where each day is priced individually.

is there a more ideal way to set up this up, or is my idea to add the new table the best way to set this up for what i need it to do?

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, your prices are valid only for a specific time.

So you need a table to store that information. In this case i would suggest a table like this:

```
product_id   price  valid_from  valid_to    
1            14.99  2013-09-07  2013-09-08  
1            16.99  2013-09-09  2013-09-10  
1            17.99  2013-09-11  2013-09-12
```

So now you can query the current price with:

```
SELECT PRICE
  FROM PRICES
 WHERE PRODUCT_ID = %yourproduct%
   AND %current_date% BETWEEN VALID_FROM AND VALID_TO
```

For the invoices, i would store the paid price seperately with the invoice. That makes backups of the invoicing data much easier and visits of the IRS and the like much less painfull.

Comment: i have that working fine, i can pull up appropriate rates for the specific time i need. the problem is when a transaction happens i need to store the price the customer paid, the difficult part is since they can buy tickets for events that span multiple days. each day should have it's own ticket price, i can't just store the total price (because of business logic reasons)

Comment: Maybe create some kind of hierarchy for the products. Create products in a way, that they have a specific (determinable) price for a given timeframe. Then create products that consist of multiple of those elemental products. 
But this isn't really a programming question, this is just design. You mentioned business logic reasons for why you can't store the total price. I don't know those reasons as I don't know your business. 
But it seems a little weird to me. I mean you hopefully display the full price to the customer at some point, right? So why don't you just take this price?